# How to draw arrow with one right-turn in PowerPoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I would like to draw an arrow with a "single turn" in Microsoft PowerPoint, but it seems impossible; the only option that I have is "Elbow Arrow", which has "two turns".

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I need to connect both ends of the arrow to the objects. Then the body of the arrow will "snap".

Comment: don't forget to mark your answer as accepted, check [answer] and the [tour] if you have doubts.

Comment: Thanks for reminding; I was not able to accept my own answer in the first day.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an arrow head shape
Insert> Shape> Triangle
...then from the same Shape dropdown use the elbow connector and snap one end to the triangle, then group the two objects together.

Answer (score 0):

Just create two straight lines, One at 0 degrees, One at 90 degrees. They can connect together to form a right angle.